# Maven Dependency Convergence

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, dependencies, dependency-management

The site generated for a multi-module Maven project contains a "Dependency Convergence" section, which is useful for detecting dependency conflicts.

In the site report for a simple (i.e. jar package) Maven project the "Dependency Convergence" is missing. Why is this and is it possible to generate it for simple projects?

I'm using Maven 2.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/configuring-reports.html) tells you how to configure the reports that are incorporated into your "site" documentation.  Basically, the "Dependency Convergence" report is *not generated by default*.  So (I guess) the multi-module project you were looking at had this report configured explicitly.

(The link above is for the Maven 2/3 "site" plugin.  If you are using the old Maven 2 only plugin, check the corresponding documentation.  I don't think this aspect has changed, but I didn't check.)